# Where are these garbage values coming from?

Tags: c++, string

I have written this function that reverses the order of words within a string, the function behaves as expected until it has read two words then starts to behave unexpectedly:

```
string ReverseString(string InputString){

int EndOfGroup = 0;

string ReversedString = " ";
int k = 0;

ReversedString.resize(InputString.size());
for (int i = InputString.length();  i > 0; i--){
    if (isspace(InputString[i]))
    {           
        EndOfGroup = i;

        for (int j = i; j >= EndOfGroup && j < InputString.length(); j++)
        {

            ReversedString[k] = InputString[j] ;
            k++;

        }
    }

}
```

What I mean by behaves unexpectedly is that once I pass a string to the function it starts to populate the ReversedString variable with garbage values until the goes out of bounds.

This shoes the point the programme crashes:

```
InputString "the brown fox died"    
ReversedString  " died fox died brownÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍýýýý««««««««îþîþ"  
j   9   
i   3
EndOfGroup  3   
k   20
```

This is not a duplicate question as my method is different to existing methods out there.

Comment: Cool. Did you try to debug it yourself? You can easily do that by stepping-over every statement (F-10 key on VS). And by adding _watches_ or just hoovering your mouse over the variables to see what is exactly going on?

Comment: @FirstStep I have the output of the debugger when the programme crashes is in my question, it shows how the ReveresedString is populated with the wrong values

Comment: I recommend using either K&R bracing or Allman bracing, but not both in the same code. (Well, I *really* recommend Allman bracing, but honestly speaking, consistency is more important than which you pick)

Comment: @FirstStep Thanks, I had the wrong idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think about the inner loop,

```
for (int j = i; j >= EndOfGroup && j < InputString.length(); j++)
```

For the first word, this is good, now for the second word - are the conditions correct?

Remember you are writing to the reversed string using an incrementing index `k`...

Comment: I think this is when things start to get funny, I have tested it with two words only and it only outputs one!

Comment: Use the debugger to step over your code and see exactly what it's doing.

Comment: Right, my hint - which should allow you to solve your problem is to check the conditions of the loop..

Comment: So far I know that  j >= EndOfGroup is redundant

Comment: Aha, once it encounters the second space it does not stop writing to the ReversedString it only stops at the end of the sentance. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You are copying the word only when you are meeting `space` sign

```
if (isspace(InputString[i]))
{
    //start of copying...
```

what does mean that you will not copy the first work (there is no space before `the` word).

`resize()` method is fullfilling the string will `null` character ([due to reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/resize/)) and they are probably show as

```
    ÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍýýýý««««««««îþîþ
```

You need to handle the first word

```
    for (int i = InputString.length();  i >= 0; i--){
        if (isspace(InputString[i]) || i == 0)
```

Also it would be good to provide some default `char` instead of null by using

```
    ReversedString.resize(InputString.size(), ' ');
```

Comment: this is not the problem, the outer loop is correct, however the conditions of the inner loop is not correct - hence there is a buffer overflow...